# Accessing Form Post Values in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I feel like this should be pretty simple, but how can I access the Form POST value collection from a dynamic form (basically a standard HTML form, not using EditForms)?

I call this to render the form:

```
    public async Task<string> GetAgencyForm()
    {
        return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync($"form/create/");
    }
```

I place it in the page like this:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var content = await agencyFormService.GetAgencyForm();
        renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenElement(1, "p");
            builder.AddContent(2, new MarkupString(content));
            builder.CloseElement();
        };
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
```

The form renders like this:

```
<form id="AgencyForm" method="post">
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<input id="Name" name="Name" value="">
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Upon submit, how would I access the "Name" value? Also, the form parameter may change depending on some parameters. How can I get the whole collection of values?

Comment: So why are you building your form in HTML?  Why not just do it in a Blazor Form?  Submit in the Html form actually submits the page back to the server definitely not an SPA activity.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I would prefer to use a Blazor Form, however I do not have control over how the forms render (it's a separate framework). I was hoping to still capture the values in some way despite how the form is rendered.

Comment: As almost anything is "possible", you may get lucky and get an answer.  The best cludge I can think of is creating a form interpreter to rebuild `content` into a Blazor form.   Good luck.